# Why do I need to add "classpath:" to ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I'm trying to learn Spring Framework and reading book about it. I'm at ApplicationContext topic now and I don't understand why there is "classpath:" in `ctx.load()` method

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(); 
ctx.load("classpath:spring/app-context-xml.xml"); 
ctx.refresh();
```

It seems to work fine without adding this "classpath:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference here, is when you are packaging your application. If the file specified is packed into the jar, it won't resolve it at runtime, as there is no dedicated file present. However, it will be present at the application's classpath.

Answer (score 1):

That's coming from [Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/resources.html). Other options would be using https:// for eg.

PS You are probably looking at an older version of Spring, configuring Spring via XML is quite out of fashion nowadays, in favour of annotations. Have a look at Spring Boot too.

Comment: I'm reading "Spring 5 for professionals" as my friend advised it to me and he is junior Java developer at company that uses XML configuration in their project. Other developers told me its 50/50 for annotations and xml.